# как хранятся структуры в C/C++ и классы

Tags: c++, c

при компиляции программы , компилятор видит структуру и запоминает ее размер(с выравниванием), и уже при создании переменной он видит тип переменной, который занимает сколько то уже места, выделяет участок памяти под эту переменную(про локальный стек вызова, кучу не трогаю)? потом создаем еще переменную с именем структуры, он на тебе еще памяти.так все происходит? и как я понимаю в С память под структуры выделяется непрерывным блоком, и я могу ее например кастовать к (char *) и побайтово пробежаться типа memcpy, а объекты под классы в с++ тоже так же выделяются непрерывно и по ним можно побайтово пробежаться?

```
    struct test
{
    int i;
    int j;
};
int main()
{
    test ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

когда мы создаем ptr, как он знает что ему надо выделить участок в 8 байт?

Comment: имена переменных и типов существуют только во время компиляции

Comment: Классы в Си++ это такие-же структуры. При классах с виртуальными функциями, ещё добавляется к структуре служебные данные типа класса.

Comment: Где всё в памяти расставлено, говориться здесь : http://scrutator.me/post/2014/01/29/objects_memory_layout_p1.aspx